# Sarg report error

Tags: squid, logrotate

I have a proxy server that runs Ubuntu Server 11.10, Squid 2.7.STABLE9. I installed sarg (version 2.3.1 Sep-18-2010) to generate reports using the ordinary apt-get install, and added a cron job to generate a report of the day every 5 minutes (that will overwrite the 5-minutes-older one):

```
*/5 * * * * /root/proxy_report.sh
```

And the content of `/root/proxy_report.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/sarg -nd `date +"%d/%m/%Y"` > /dev/null 2>&1
```

And I added another cron job to generate a full report every hour at :32 (not to collide with the 5 minutes job):

```
*/32 * * * * /root/proxy_report_full.sh
```

And the content of `/root/proxy_report_full.sh` is :

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/sarg -n > /dev/null 2>&1
```

And I added a small script to remove the yesterday full report (the full report that ends in yesterday that won't be overwritten by the new today full report) in `/etc/rc.local` to run at startup:

```
/usr/bin/rm_yesterday.sh &>> /var/log/rm_yesterday
```

Where `/usr/bin/rm_yesterday.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /var/www/sarg/ | grep `date -d Apr1 +"%Y%b%d"`-* | grep -v `date +"%Y%b%d"` | xargs rm -rf
```

* Apr1 is the starting date of the proxy...

** I've placed it in `/usr/bin` to be mounted early at startup...

That arrangement went OK for about a month and a half, except for one time I noticed some errors and reports wasn't generated, and fixed that by making an offset (the two minutes in 32 of the second cron job). However, it then started not to generate reports anymore. By manually trying to generate it it gives the following error:

```
root@proxy-server:~# sarg -n
SARG: getword_atoll loop detected after 3 bytes.
SARG: Line="154 192.168.10.40 TCP_MISS/200 39 CONNECT www.google.com"
SARG: Record="154 192.168.10.40 TCP_MISS/200 39 CONNECT www.google.com"
SARG: searching for 'x2f'
SARG: getword backtrace:
SARG: 1:sarg() [0x8050a4a]
SARG: 2:sarg() [0x8050c8b]
SARG: 3:sarg() [0x804fc2e]
SARG: 4:/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x129113]
SARG: 5:sarg() [0x80501c9]
SARG: Maybe you have a broken date in your /var/log/squid/access.log file
```

When I looked to `/var/log/squid/` folder, I noticed that it contains some rotated logs:

```
root@proxy-server:~# ls /var/log/squid/
access.log  access.log.1  cache.log  cache.log.1  store.log  store.log.1
```

So maybe sarg installed logrotate with it? Or it comes with the standard Ubuntu? I don't remember I installed it manuallly.

**The question is**: What could've gone wrong? Does it have something to do with rotating the log? How can I trace the error and start generating reports again?

Comment: logrotate is installed by default on ubuntu. Squid probably provides the necessary logrotation per default, have a look in `/etc/logrotate.d`

Comment: @Ulrich yes I found the squid script. But can this be a problem -to rotate logs? can sarg understand the rotated log?

Comment: I don't know sarg so i can't answer it but it seems it has a problem with your access.log. Try to use ltrace or strace to debug your problem

Comment: i just googled and yes the logrotation seems to be the problem - http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=369693 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/squid/+bug/268816

Comment: For 32-minutes-past-the-hour, wouldn't the minute field be `32` instead of `*/32`, which as I understand it would mean "every 32 minutes", which could potentially confuse the cron daemon.

Comment: @killermist yp I've changed it..

Comment: Is `proxy_report.sh` still working where `proxy_report_full.sh` continues to fail?

Comment: @killermist No, they both fail.

Comment: Ah, if they're both failing, then it looks like @UlrichDangel may have found the problem.

Comment: @UlrichDangel can you please put it in the form of an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all i don't know sarg but it seems that the problem is caused by your logfile. This could be caused by two things:

1. Random characters / binary data / changed log format of your squid configuration
2. sarg may have a problem with log files rotated by `logrotate`

Based on http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=369693 as well as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/squid/+bug/268816 i think the problem may be caused by logrotate.